# How do I drill down within this XML to ONLY extract the tag data that I desire under the <InvoiceHeader> tag?

Tags: excel, xml, vba, import

I'm trying to import an XML file into a spreadshet using Excel VBA. Although it's working, I'm importing the entire XML when I ONLY want to extract particular tag data from the file and insert the data from each specific tag into my spreadsheet a couple rows over from my active cell. For example...

```
ActiveCell = A1
PurchaseOrder  into   A2
InvoiceNumber   into  A3
BuyerCurrency   into  A4





Sub cmdImportDataFromFile()

Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Dim myRow As ListRow
    Dim row_number As Integer
    

With fd

    If .Show = True Then
    
        xmlfilename = .SelectedItems(1)
        
        'Process the file
        Dim fDoc As Object
        Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        xDoc.async = False: xDoc.validateonparse = False
        xDoc.Load (xmlfilename)
        
        'Get Root Node
        Set selInvoice = xDoc.DocumentElement
        
        'row_number = 6
        For Each InvoiceHeader In selInvoice.ChildNodes
        
            Debug.Print "<InvoiceNumber>:" & InvoiceHeader.ChildNodes(0).text
            Debug.Print "<PurchaseOrderNumber>:" & InvoiceHeader.ChildNodes(1).text
            'Debug.Print "<PurchaseOrderNumber>:" & Product.ChildNodes(0).text
            Debug.Print "----------------------"

           ActiveCell(1, 1).Value = invoiceheader.ChildNodes(0).text
            ActiveCell(1, 2).Value = invoiceheader.ChildNodes(1).text
    
        Next InvoiceHeader
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

[Sample XML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDMh6.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are several points to consider when trying to get the  textual contents of single nodes:

- As your xml files contain a namespace declaration you'll have to integrate this, too in order to be able to use XPath expressions addressing nodes directly.
- You are potentially confusing the subordonated levels under the individual invoice(s); the order of needed nodes actually is: `Invoices/Invoice/Header/InvoiceHeader/...`
- Furthermore you should reference the latest xml version via `CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0"`(conform to your post using late binding).

**Example call**

```
'1) Get File name
' ... 
' xmlfilename = ... 

'2) Set xml document to memory in its latest version 6.0 (late binding)
    Dim xDoc As Object: Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
'3) Add namespace
    xDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
    "xmlns:n='http://www.xxxxxx.com'"                                   ' note the udf n-prefix
'4) Load xml file
    If xDoc.Load(xmlfilename) Then
        Dim invoice As Object, invoices As Object
        'a) addressing Invoice indirectly (being the next hierarchy level under DocumentElement)
        Set invoices = xDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
        'b) addressing Invoice directly using namespace prefix n:
        ''  Set invoices = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//n:Invoice")

        For Each invoice In invoices
            ' assuming actual text content in wanted nodes
            ' (otherwise dim tmp as object, set tmp = ... and recheck via If Not tmp Is Nothing then ...)
            Debug.Print String(29, "-")
            Debug.Print "InvoiceNumber:       " & invoice.SelectSingleNode("n:*/n:*/n:InvoiceNumber").Text
            Debug.Print "PurchaseOrderNumber: " & invoice.SelectSingleNode("n:*/n:*/n:PurchaseOrderNumber").Text
        Next
    End If
```

**Example file (e.g. invoices.xml)**

For testing purposes, you might want to copy the following xml file content to your hard disk:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoices xmlns="http://www.xxxxxx.com">
  <Invoice>
    <PaymentTerms>
    </PaymentTerms>
    <Header>
      <InvoiceHeader>
        <InvoiceNumber>3000380</InvoiceNumber>
        <PurchaseOrderNumber>96428312</PurchaseOrderNumber>
      </InvoiceHeader>
      <PaymentTerms>
      </PaymentTerms>
    </Header>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </Invoice>
  <Invoice>
    <Header>
      <InvoiceHeader>
        <InvoiceNumber>3000381</InvoiceNumber>
        <PurchaseOrderNumber>96428313</PurchaseOrderNumber>
      </InvoiceHeader>
    </Header>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

**Output in immediate window:**

```
-----------------------------
InvoiceNumber:       3000380
PurchaseOrderNumber: 96428312
-----------------------------
InvoiceNumber:       3000381
PurchaseOrderNumber: 96428313
```

Comment: I see that my solution is incorrect.  As a result, I have deleted it.  Thank you very much for pointing it out.  I really appreciate it.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for feedback; nevertheless I think it wouldn't be necessary to delete it, as it meant the right direction (wd' even upv' as I think it could be helpful to show different approaches) @Domenic

Comment: Actually, I missed the fact that the XML file contains a user-defined namespace.  And so the `SelectSingleNode` method returns nothing unless it's addressed.  You correctly addressed it, and so I gave you a +1.  So all is good.  Cheers!  :-)

Comment: @Domenic Sorry I confused your name with the author of this question ICater. Thanks anyway for contributing.